# Prevent new data from showing between running of query and completion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple set of SQL queries (`SELECT * FROM TABLE`) for transporting data from a number of related tables, that take about 30 seconds to run. I would like the data returned to exclude any changes that take place during that 30 seconds. The query can't return an error when there is new data inserted and transactions can't be blocked or locked from occurring. I also don't have access to any server settings and am looking for a SQL command to achieve this.

If a field called TRN_ID and is in TABLE_SHORT and TABLE_LONG, and TRN_ID is created during that 30 second window, I want to ensure that the TRN_ID in my 2 queries will be consistent.

Edit: Here's my order of operations:

1. Run query - SELECT * FROM TABLEA
2. Insert new row into TABLEA & TABLEB
3. Select from related table TABLEB ensuring that only rows related to the rows present in my query in 1. are included.

Comment: Doesn't it work that way automatically?

Comment: It would, @DaleK, as there is a shared lock on the table, blocking updates to it. Unless the OP is using a certain isolation level or a certain table hint; but then they have by definition stated they *want* to potentially see the changes (and the dirty reads, and the ghost data, etc etc).

Comment: @Larnu they said the want to exclude any changes that take place during that 30 seconds. So basically the OP described what happens when selecting data from a table. My guess though is they are experiencing some locking when other people are trying to insert or update data.

Comment: Yes, it's unclear what they are really asking, @SeanLange . (Note, my "it would [work that way automatically]" is in agreement with Dale, not me saying it would include the changed data).

Comment: Here's my order of operations:

1. Run query - SELECT * FROM TABLE
2. Insert new row into TABLE
3. Query from step 1 returns data, but it includes the row from step 2. I'm looking for the data from the table without that row or any other changes that have occurred in the table after running the query

Comment: "exclude any changes that take place during that 30 seconds" is that 
Updates of rows already read?
Updates of rows yet to be read?
Rows to be inserted?

Comment: @DaleK, it doesn't work that way automatically for me. I haven't been able to find anything that's close to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not quite sure what other keywords to use in my search.

Comment: You would research locking hints and mechanisms.

Comment: You can always use a "WITH (TABLOCK)" query hint to lock the table while your select is running, but it really shouldn't make a difference for your query, and other users using the table aren't going to like it.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour, @Branden . You can see in the followingt this [animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdD0j.gif) that even though I `INSERT` 2 more rows into `dbo.SomeTable`, the query only returns 10,000,000 rows, not 30,000,000.

Comment: What about `SNAPSHOT` isolation, that should give you the exact effect you want

Comment: @TheImpaler `READ COMMITTED` on SQL Server absolutely does not work like that, only `SNAPSHOT` does. If a query reads a ton of rows from a table and another query begins and commits an insert further along the index, those rows would still be read. If the commit has not happened then query 1 gets blocked

Comment: @Charlieface This is news to me. I stand corrected.

Comment: Given the updated info, I can't see any way to do this without introducing locking hints or altering the transaction isolation level on the SELECT, namely WITH TABLOCK, which would block the other session which is out scope?
I suppose a further question would be, why do you not want the newly inserted data?

Comment: @TheImpaler Required reading I think https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels

Comment: Still working my way through all this new information (thanks!), but @SEarle1986, I'm transporting a bunch of related tables. If a field called TRN_ID and is in TABLE_SHORT and TABLE_LONG, and TRN_ID is created during that 30 second window, then TRN_ID in my 2 tables will be inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe update your question explaining the problem you're trying to solve (the transportation problem) with table definitions of the two tables, including any PK / FKs on the tables as its difficult to visualize without that

Comment: Depending on the context of your task shapshot or read committed snapshot is worth to consider.

Comment: I think what you need is to create a database snapshot and read all your data from that. A DB snapshot is an efficient mechanism for creating a frozen in time version of your database. It takes up very little space as your original db is used for most reads, only pages that have been changed are stored in your snapshot, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The other way to solve your problem is to save your original results to a temporary table and your subsequent queries can use an EXISTS clause to ensure only related records are returned.